# Declaring a Python list of expressions without evaluating each

Tags: python, list

I have a large number of arithmetic expressions that I store in a list. For example

```
exp_list = [exp1, exp2, ...,exp10000]
```

I also have indices of the few expressions I need to evaluate.

```
inds = [ind1,ind2,...,ind10]
exp_selected =  [exp_list[i] for i in inds ]
```

Is there a way to avoid having to evaluate all the expressions in exp_list?

Comment: What dos exp1..n look like?  Are they expressions stored as strings?  If not they will evaluate when you declare the list literal.  Maybe they are functions?

Comment: how is it evaluating all the expressions in exp_list, is there missing code?

Comment: define `evaluate`?

Comment: exp1...n  are arithmetic expressions. I will edit to make it clear.

Comment: If you write something like `exp_list = [1+1, 1+2, 1+3]` then the expressions will be evaluated immediately to give `exp_list = [2, 3, 4]`

Comment: Define a function for each or write them as lambdas or create a function that has all the expressions mapped to an *index* with the function parameter being the *index* so the expression executes only when the function is called with its *index*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you decide to store you expressions as lambdas (to avoid them being immediately evaluated) then you could selectively evaluate them with a simple list comprehension:

```
exp_list = [lambda: 1+2, lambda: 3+4, lambda: 5+6, lambda: 7+8]
inds = [1, 3]
print [exp() for i, exp in enumerate(exp_list) if i in inds]
```

Produces:

```
[7, 15]
```

Answer (score 0):

If those expressions share some pattern and can be created 'mid-air' it would be better to use generator instead of just creating the list. Especially if you don't need to remember the results, but just check if any (or all) of them are true/false.